# golang concurrent http request handling

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency, httpserver

I am creating a simple http server using golang. I have two questions, one is more theoretic and another one about the real program.

1. Concurrent request handling

I create a server and use s.ListenAndServe() to handle the requests.
As much as I understand the requests served concurrently. I use a simple handler to check it:

```
func  ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {  
    fmt.Println("1")  
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)       //Phase 2 delete this line
    fmt.Fprintln(rw, "Hello, world.")
    fmt.Println("2")  
}
```

I see that if I send several requests, I will see all the "1" appear and only after a second all the "2" appear.
But if I delete the Sleep line, I see that program never start a request before it finishes with the previous one (the output is 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...).
So I don't understand, if they are concurrent or not really. If they are I would expect to see some mess in prints...

2. The real life problem

In the real handler, I send the request to another server and return the answer to the user (with some changes to request and the answer but in idea it is kind of a proxy). All this of course takes time and from what can see (by adding some prints to the handler), the requests are handled one by one, with no concurrency between them (my prints show me that a request starts, go through all the steps, ends and only then I see a new start....). 
What can I do to make them really concurrent?
Putting the handler function as goroutine gives an error, that body of the request is already closed. Also if it is already concurrent adding more goroutines will make things only worse.

Thank you!

Comment: The requests are concurrent by default. Whatever goes on inside a handler is sequential unless you use goroutines.

Comment: Your way of checking if the request are handled concurrent is flawed. All the request are always handled in a concurrent fashion no matter what your print statements make you think.

Comment: I would suggest you to send concurrent requests to you're server and see what happens!

Comment: @FranckJeannin Of course inside the handler, everything is sequential, but if the handlers run in the same time then the prints may interapt one inside the other. If you create 10 goroutins and every one will print numbers 1 - 100 and you start them all you will not see 1, 2, 3, ..., 100, 1, 2, ..., 100, 1, 2.... . But you will see a mess inside like: 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3, ...

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande I sent concurrent requests in my test (a python script with 10 threads each thread sends 10 requestst)

Comment: @Volker then why don't I see concurrent prints? I changed the test handler to print numbers 1 to 100 and sent requests from 20 concurrent threads, but all the prints are sequential without any interrupting... How can it be if the requests handled concurrently?

Comment: what are you printing in you're handlers?

Comment: The thing is, when you remove the Sleep, your goroutine is so quick to execute that the probability that another goroutine will run *during* the time it takes to print "1" and "2" is close to zero. The compiler may even decide that your two prints can be combined into one atomic print, etc.

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande in my sample i printed just numbers 1 to 100. Now I increased it to 1-100000 and when I run this code I see some interruptions, but less then I would expect. In the real handler, I proxy the request to other server and then return the answer to user. In the middle I add some prints to see the how much each step takes in format: 1 [time], 2[ time], 3 [ time] ...., and I see that all my prints are sequential. Proxy the request to other server takes time and I would expect that in this time other handlers would run (and print) as well...

Comment: @FranckJeannin you are right, this is why started to increase the numbers. 1-100 it was still sequential. 1-100000 I start to see some interruptions. But in my real handler there are moment when I send a request to other server, and wait until I get the answer... so there is a plenty of time to switch to another request. And still I don't see such switches but all the prints there are sequential too.

Comment: [The documentation states](https://godoc.org/net/http#Serve) that a goroutine is created to service the requests on a connection.

Answer (score 7):

Your example makes it very hard to tell what is happening.

The below example will clearly illustrate that the requests are run in parallel.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if len(r.FormValue("case-two")) > 0 {
            fmt.Println("case two")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("case one start")
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
            fmt.Println("case one end")
        }
    })

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Make one request to http://localhost:8000

Make another request to http://localhost:8000?case-two=true within 5 seconds

console output will be

```
case one start
case two
case one end
```

Comment: On top of the transparency that @jmaloney's codes provides.  It would also be best to send concurrent requests using a tool like Siege, https://www.joedog.org/siege-home/

Answer (score 1):

It does serve requests in a concurrent fashion as can be seen here in the source https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L2293.

Here is a **contrived example**:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    go startServer()
    sendRequest := func() {
        resp, _ := http.Get("http://localhost:8000/")
        defer resp.Body.Close()
    }
    start := time.Now()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    ch := make(chan int, 10)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(n int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            sendRequest()
            ch <- n
        }(i)
    }
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()

    fmt.Printf("completion sequence :")
    for routineNumber := range ch {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", routineNumber)
    }
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("time:", time.Since(start))
}

func startServer() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    })
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Over several runs it is easy to visualize that the completion ordering of the go routines which send the requests are completely random and given the fact that channels are fifo, we can summarize that the server handled the requests in a concurrent fashion, irrespective of whether HandleFunc sleeps or not.
(Assumption being all the requests start at about the same time).

In addition to the above, if you did sleep for a second in HandleFunc, the time it takes to complete all 10 routines is consistently 1.xxx seconds which further shows that the server handled the requests concurrently as else the total time to complete all requests should have been 10+ seconds.

**Example:**

```
completion sequence :3 0 6 2 9 4 5 1 7 8 
time: 1.002279359s

completion sequence :7 2 3 0 6 4 1 9 5 8 
time: 1.001573873s

completion sequence :6 1 0 8 5 4 2 7 9 3 
time: 1.002026465s
```

Analyzing concurrency by printing without synchronization is almost always indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

While Go serves requests concurrently, the client might actually be blocking (wait for the first request to complete before sending the second), and then one will see exactly the behavior reported initially.

I was having the same problem, and my client code was sending a "GET" request via XMLHttpRequest to a slow handler (I used a similar handler code as posted above, with 10 sec timeout). In turns out that such requests block each other. Example JavaScript client code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "/slowhandler");
  xhr.send();
}
```

Note that `xhr.send()` will return immediately, since this is an asynchronous call, but that doesn't guarantee that the browser will send the actual "GET" request right away.

GET requests are subject to caching, and if one tries to GET the same URL, caching might (in fact, will) affect how the requests to the server are made. POST requests are not cached, so if one changes `"GET"` to `"POST"` in the example above, the Go server code will show that the `/slowhandler` will be fired concurrently (you will see "1 1 1 [...pause...] 2 2 2" printed).